# android doesn't recognize org.apache.commons.validator

Tags: android, url

I want to check the validity of a URL address, so after some research, i find that using apache.commons.validator.UrlValidator class is a good solution to do that, this is an example of code :

```
    import org.apache.commons.validator.UrlValidator;

    public class ValidateUrlExample{

public static void main(String[] args) {

    UrlValidator urlValidator = new UrlValidator();

    //valid URL
    if (urlValidator.isValid("http://www.mkyong.com")) {
       System.out.println("url is valid");
    } else {
       System.out.println("url is invalid");
    }

    //invalid URL
    if (urlValidator.isValid("http://invalidURL^$&%$&^")) {
        System.out.println("url is valid");
    } else {
        System.out.println("url is invalid");
    }

}
}
```

but android doesn't recognize the class "org.apache.commons.validator"
Does anyone know what should I do to fix that ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: FYI If you use `new URL("putyoururlhere")` with a invalid url, it throws a `MalformedURLException` - maybe you can use it. More info at http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URL.html#URL(java.lang.String)

Comment: I will take your solution into consideration, Thank you

Comment: I tried your solution, I tested it with this string just like that : myurl = new URL(":putyoururlhere") , but it don't throw me the malformedUrlException, but it thrower me a  java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException and Force close the app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you still want to use the apache commons validator library, then you just need to download [the library](http://commons.apache.org/validator/download_validator.cgi) and package it with your app.

Comment: thank you, however, I need to know if i should download the binary or the source file ? and also where to package it in my app ? Thank you for your time

Comment: Download the binary file and extract the commons-validator-1.4.0.jar file.  Details on how to add the library to your app can be found [here](http://developer.android.com/resources/faq/commontasks.html#addexternallibrary).

Comment: I realized that this class "org.apache.commons.validator" is deprecated, so I had rather import the new version : instead of that : import org.apache.commons.validator.UrlValidator; I did that : import org.apache.commons.validator.routines.UrlValidator;

Answer (score 7):

You can use the method [`isValidUrl()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/URLUtil.html#isValidUrl%28java.lang.String%29) defined in `android.webkit.URLUtil`.
For example

```
if (!URLUtil.isValidUrl("yourUrl")
   // do something
```

Comment: @Martin: it is usually best if your edits can be made as 'quiet' as possible; for example, I inlined the URL into the first reference of the method.